# Showing the contents of a file

Tags: c, file

This program reads a filename from standard input and then prints its content. Please review:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()

{
    char fileName[20];

    // Get the filename from the user:
    int fileNameLength = read(0,fileName,19);
    // We need to get rid of the new line character caused by terminal
    // Replace the new line character with \0 
    fileName[fileNameLength-1] = fileName[fileNameLength];

    printf("You want to see the contents of: %s\n", fileName);

    // open the file:
    int fd = 0;
    fd = open(fileName,O_RDONLY);

    if(fd == -1) {
        // Something went wrong, perhaps no such file:
        perror(NULL);
        printf("%s\n", fileName);
    } else {
        // Read until the read method returns 0 bytes. 
        char buf[20];
        int numBytesRead = read(fd,buf,20);
        while(numBytesRead) {
            write(1,buf,numBytesRead);
            numBytesRead = read(fd,buf,20);
        }
        close(fd);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

And in action:

> ```
> Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ gcc koray.c
> Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ ./a.out 
> k.txt
> You want to see the contents of: k.txt
> Hello Code Review!
> This is the contents of k.txt.
> Have a good day!
> Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$
> ```

Comment: perror("open") would be better.

Comment: Also writing errors on stderr would be better.

Comment: Also don't hesitate to use 4096 or 8192 buffers instead of 20, greatly reducing the number of syscall (which are slow).

Comment: For the filename buffer it exists a constant named PATH_MAX, better use a system dependent define that a hard coded and obviously too short one.

Comment: No error checking on `read`, silly hard coded limits on filename length, why read filename from standard input instead of command line? wrong assumptions about uninitialized local variables... A lot of work needed.

Comment: @chqrlie when can you start

Comment: @JulienPalard and chqrlie: All suggestions for improvements belong in answers. Comments will be removed shortly.

Comment: Go ahead remove them, but this make no sense to me, they are not answers, just atomic points.

Comment: @JulienPalard Where is PATH_MAX defined?

Comment: @chqrlie Why read from command line? That is a design decision..

Comment: To find PATH_MAX, read the doc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Magic numbers 20 and 19?

Instead of this:

> ```
> char fileName[20];
>
> // Get the filename from the user:
> int fileNameLength = read(0,fileName,19);
> ```

Define `MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH` somewhere, and use that as the buffer size parameter, and `MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH + 1` as the array size containing the buffer, to account for the terminating null character.

#### Write in code your intention exactly

Write in code more explicitly what you want.
For example here you say in comment that you want to write a `\0` to the final position of the `char[]`, but the code doesn't do exactly that:

> ```
> // We need to get rid of the new line character caused by terminal
> // Replace the new line character with \0 
> fileName[fileNameLength-1] = fileName[fileNameLength];
> ```

Don't assume what might be at an uninitialized memory location.
If you want to set the terminating character to `\0`,
then do exactly that:

```
fileName[fileNameLength-1] = '\0';
```

#### More magic number 20

All those 20 everywhere:

> ```
> char buf[20];
> int numBytesRead = read(fd,buf,20);
> while(numBytesRead) {
>     write(1,buf,numBytesRead);
>     numBytesRead = read(fd,buf,20);
> }
> ```

Why not introduce a variable so that you can change it later if you want to:

```
int bufsize = 20;
char buf[bufsize];
int numBytesRead = read(fd,buf,bufsize);
while(numBytesRead) {
    write(1,buf,numBytesRead);
    numBytesRead = read(fd,buf,bufsize);
}
```

And why use a buffer of size 20? Why read a file 20 byte at a time? It would be faster to read in larger chunks. Surely you have enough memory to load 4 kbyte at a time. Luckily, now it's easy to change that:

```
int bufsize = 4096;
```

#### Avoid code duplication

In the previous code snippet, `read(fd,buf,bufsize);` appears twice,
which is not pretty. It can be rewritten without such duplication:

```
int numBytesRead;
while ((numBytesRead = read(fd, buf, bufsize)) > 0) {
    write(1, buf, numBytesRead);
}
close(fd);
```

On the other hand, some people find this writing style potentially error prone or confusing. In my opinion code duplication is the bigger evil,
so I still prefer this writing style, which is also shorter.

#### Comments stating the obvious

> ```
> // open the file:
> int fd = 0;
> fd = open(fileName,O_RDONLY);
> ```

Is that comment *really* necessary there? Or is it just noise?

#### Pointless variable initialization

> ```
> int fd = 0;
> fd = open(fileName,O_RDONLY);
> ```

If you're going to set `fd` to something else, why set it to 0?

#### Usability

When you run the program,
it prints nothing,
it's just waiting for user input.
It would be better to print a prompt,
for example:

```
puts("Enter file name:");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to not repeat the read() of the file statement.  I had not placed that in my answer, as I did not want to make suggestions that might confuse the OP.

Comment: Do not encourage error prone constructs such as `while(numBytesRead = read(fd, buf, bufsize))`

Comment: This construct is error prone because of the combined assignment/test.  I recommend writing: `while((numBytesRead = read(fd, buf, bufsize)) > 0)`.  `gcc -Wall -W -Werror` does not let me compile your code, and also finds more subtle problems and bugs.

Comment: Thanks @chqrlie, that's the kind of reasoning I was looking for. I updated my post.

Comment: The OP uses the low level system call interface instead of the standard library stream functions from `<stdio.h>`.  This is not a good idea in general.  The call ` write(1, buf, numBytesRead);` for instance may return a number less than `numBytesRead` if writing to a device or a pipe, or if it was interrupted by a signal.  The programmer needs to handle these conditions.  It is much simpler and not necessarily less efficient to use higher level functions.

Comment: Another gotcha: if `MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH` is the maximum length for a filename, the buffer size should be `MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH+1`.  The standard macro `FILENAME_MAX` is meant to be used as a buffer size.

Comment: Somewhere I read that read must be called once before entering a loop. I can not remember where and why :)

Answer (score 8):

Running the posted code through gcc, with parameters:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

causes the compiler to raise three warnings.

1. unused variable: 'fileFound'
2. unused parameter: 'argc'
3. unused parameter: 'argv'

Please, where posting code that 'works' be sure that it cleanly compiles.

I suggest using `int main( void)` rather than `int main(int argc, char const *argv[]), and removing the line`int fileFound = 0;`.

Regarding the call to `read()` to get the file name from the user:

1. Always check the returned value from `read()` to assure the operation was successful. (in the future, I suggest using `getline()`).
2. Regarding this line `fileName[...-1] = fileName[...]`, which is copying a trash character over the last input character from the user, I suggest: 
   `fileName[fileNameLength-1] = '\0'; // eliminate newline` to properly terminate the fileName string

When wanting the user to input something, (in this case, a file name), the code should always output a prompt that tells the user what they are expected to input. Otherwise the user is left looking at a blinking cursor and no indication of what they (the user) is expected to do.

Regarding the line `while(numBytesRead) {`, if there is any kind of `read()` error, then the returned value will be `< 0`, which will not cause the while loop to exit. I suggest `while( 0 < numBytesRead ) {` instead.

The latest C standard allows not placing a `return(0);` statement at the end of the `main()` function. However older versions do not make the `return(0);` assumption; so I suggest inserting a final line containing the `return(0);` statement.

Comment: Your post is a little difficult to understand. I recommend that you format your code properly.

Comment: well, I followed the suggestion to just copy the comments to an answer.  I'll modify the formatting now.

Comment: As I wrote that line, I was thinking that I was missing a detail.  I have since removed that suggestion.

Comment: @user3629249 I doubt anyone suggested you format prose as code. (See edit).